# Do I need to export a function that is used in the default arguments of another function?

Tags: r, package

Suppose my package `myPkg` has the functions

```
fn = function() 'foo'
```

and

```
ex.fn = function(arg1 = fn()) c(arg1,arg1)
```

Do I have to export `fn`? I think my question is, does the default parameters of a function within a package uses the package's namespace?

Another possible implementation would be:

```
ex.fn = function(arg1 = MyPkg::fn()) c(arg1,arg1)
```

which I'm not sure if it makes sense.